# Removing \\r\\n from a corpus is not working

Tags: r, newline, text-mining, data-cleaning, carriage-return

I have a large corpus of text and cannot remove \\r\\n from it, having tried all of the options noted in Stackflow.

```
65\\r\\n ,\\r\\n\", \"English translation of Holy Torah - Book 01\\r\\n Table"
```

I have tried various versions of c1=gsub("\r\n"," ", corp), using [], \\, and placement of ",' etc.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to remove literal `\n`, literal `\\n` or a newline character (and same for `\r`)?

Comment: I wanted to remove all the strings \\r\\n that separated he verses in the that large corpus. Thanks for asking the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a tricky one because you have to use an escape character with the "" for R and an escape character with the "" for gsub, both of which give you "\". So to do this properly in gsub, you require four slashes before each n or r.

```
gsub('\\\\n|\\\\r', '', "English translation of Holy Torah - Book 01\\r\\n Table")
```

Comment: An alternative using raw string literals in R 4 is `R'(\\n|\\r)'`.

Comment: Thank you @Omri for your guidance.  It worked perfectly well immediately!

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, would you please explain further about R'(\\n|\\r)'? I tried to google it and did not really get a clear result of how that solution may apply.  I like to learn your recommendation as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @Shawn Look for “Raw character constants” in the [R “Quotes” documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html).

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph, thank you...I read it and understand it better.